# How to fix number filters not showing up in Excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, office365, pivot-table

I am working on a dataset of receipts that has about 500,000 rows. I want to use Pivot to see which customers how many times had a bill over $1,000. The problem is that although I can apply a number filter to the column in the data sheet, the same filter doesn't work for the pivot table. Instead of applying a number filter, the pivot dropdown menu just shows me each and every bill amount. I'd appreciate any suggestions on why number filter doesn't work in Pivot?

[image: pivot drop down menu]

(I have used the bill amounts columns as a filter in Pivot table. I expected it to show me the bill amounts and also give me the options to number filter. However it only showed me amounts and gave no option to further filter the data.)

Comment: If that field is in the Page/Filter area, you cannot apply those kinds of filters.

Comment: I've tried to delete the rows which have bill amounts below $999 but the data is so big that crashes Excel. If the field doesn't filter in the pivot filter area, how can I accomplish the task otherwise?

Comment: You'd normally apply a value filter to a row/column field as appropriate for your layout. If that won't work due to the aggregations, you'd apply a check in the source data/query that returns True/False depending on the size of the item, then filter on that.